# Data modeling for Friendship/Relation for Social Networking website

Tags: database-design, nosql, datamodel, data-modeling

I want to know which site give me knowledge of data modeling specially for social networking site for nosql database?

thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. Just many new database technologies which have almost nothing in common. How to model your data depends on which database you are using. I would recommend you to consult the documentation and best-practices of the database technology you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Social networking DB schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155545/social-networking-db-schema)

Answer (score 2):

As @philip mentioned in the comments, NoSQL is an embrella term for anything but SQL, so there really isn't a single good answer when framing your question like that.

Having said that, this problem is probably best suited to be modelled using Graph Databases, such as [Neo4J](http://www.neo4j.org/) or [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/).

Some links:

- [Neo4j graph model for a social network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714963/neo4j-graph-model-for-a-social-network)
- [Representation of Database as a Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169390/representation-of-database-as-a-network)
- [Graph Databases - betting the company on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623384/graph-databases-betting-the-company-on-it)